# DynamoDB query does not return nested object

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have Object with nested Object

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Wallet")
class Wallet {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<CreditCard> cards;
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    public String getId() {return id;}
    public void  setId(String id){ this.id = id;}
    //other setter and getter
}

@DynamoDBDocument
class CreditCard{
    private String number;
    private String exp;
    private String cvv;
    //getter and setter
}
```

when I use dynamoDBMapper.scan(Wallet.class,new DynamoDBScanExpression());

It return all wallet data includes creditcard list;

But when I use query() operation, It only return Wallet object with null list of , I am sure wallet I query has credircards.

anything I missed?

Comment: can you show your query code? Do you have any project expression on query ?

Comment: Thanks @notionquest, I find the problem, I query on GSI so it doesn't return  other non key fields, my bad.